# Image from database is coming out cropped in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, bitmap, varbinary

I am using Kotlin in AS and am relatively new to it so I will try to explain as best I can. I am also using a database that stores food products and their images.

I am converting a varbinary to a bitmap and setting the bitmap in a viewHolder that is a place holder for my images. When running my app, the image is

[cutoff as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhtZF.png)

and I'm unsure why it is being cut off as such.

For now, I am hardcoding in one of the records from my image column

```
val imageText = "89504E47..."
```

and setting the image bitmap by running the string into a function that gets the bitmap and sets it to my viewHolder

```
viewHolder.productImg.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(imageText))
    /**
 * Converts a hex string to Bitmap
 *
 * @param image  hex string e.g. "FFD8FFE0..."
 * @return Bitmap
 */
private fun getBitmap(image: String): Bitmap {
    // Convert String to ByteArray
    val byteArray = Hex.stringToBytes(image)
    // Convert ByteArray Bitmap
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)
}
```

I tried playing with the XML that contains the ImageView but that does nothing

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_item_pic"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fastfood_24"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
```

Please help and I can answer any follow up questions the best I can, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In you .xml file, add this -

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

It should work
Please inform me if this works

Comment: I added it and it didn't work, unfortunately. Is there anything in that imageView I should remove that may be interfering with scaleType?

Comment: Can you please send the image drawable files so that I can implement in my Android Studio Application?

Comment: The images are being stored as VARBINARY in a database held in Azure Data Studio